# Error when trying to export plot as SVG in R

Tags: r, svg, plot

I have a simple plot of points, with x and y axis labels.  I would like to export it as an SVG so that I can do some finishing edits in a Vector graphics editor.    When I try to export it using the Save Plot as image and saving as SVG, I get the error -

```
Error:metric information not available for this device
```

It then says it is converting plot but the wheel spends forever until I force exit the program.

I believe the error has something to do with the Y axis label as it has code for lowercase delta as well as unicode. When I remove the y axis label it exports smoothly.

The `ylab` call looks like this

```
title(ylab=expression(paste)delta^{15}, "N (\u2030)"),line=1, cex.lab=1)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it programmatically with `svg(filename="quux.svg")` (plenty more options), make the plot, then `dev.off()`? It and its cousin functions (e.g., `png` and `pdf`) tend to work well. (Don't forget `dev.off()`, I've burned many moments of frustration troubleshooting around that omission.)

Comment: I'll give it a try, I would just build the plot the same way just inside the svg function, correct?

Comment: Yes, but you will see none of it until you are done, type `dev.off()`, and open it with something else (like your SVG editor).

Comment: Good news and bad news, I learned how to do something new, but... the same error still appears when I try to export anything with delta.   Error in title(ylab = expression(paste(delta^{ : 
  metric information not available for this device

Comment: Should get rid of `paste)`